# How can i keep radio button static upon a text change/add

Tags: javascript, html, css, radio-button

I have a radio button(list) Which changes texts(using JavaScript) upon clicking on the 'next' button.The text changes but the alignment is off when text gets longer which makes it not remain in a constant position.

i.e
[image]

Alignment after (shifted some places to left)
[image]

Javascript (radio is a variable defined upon as'var'):
`radio[0].nextSibling.textContent = "We can’t explore ourselves beyond our knowledge";`

HTML/CSS:

```
<div  style="position:absolute;transform: scale(2);top:80vh;left:20vw">
         <input type='radio' name='rblist1' value='0'> <br> 
         <input type='radio' name='rblist1' value='1'> <br> 
         <input type='radio' name='rblist1' value='2'>
           </div>
```

Any help would be awesome!Thanks

Comment: You can add a common css class to all radios, then in this css class, you set the fixed positon, e.g. same margin-left for radio + set width/height for div container to prevent the shifting when the text is longer.

Comment: Remove the styling from your outer div

Comment: If i remove the styling i will loose the scale attribute..

Comment: I've updated my answer. Only transform the radios and use font-size for the text. It is always a hassle using transform: scale on containers with a lot of stuff inside. Keep it simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skip the current styling and structure your radios within labels. Then browsers will know that the specified text belongs to the radio and the radio will activate when clicking the text aswell. Keep away from using transform:scale on containers with several elements and be very aware that position: absolute very often will bite you in the a...

```js
function changeText(){
  $("label>span").eq(1).text("This is an even longer text wich will test the structure of the HTML");
}
```

```css
.transformScale2{
 transform: scale(2); 
}

.inputRadioContainer{
margin-bottom: 10px;
font-size: large;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="inputRadioContainer">
    <label>
      <input type='radio' name='rblist1' value='0' class="transformScale2">
      <span>This is the label with a long text</span>
  </label>
  </div>
  <div class="inputRadioContainer">
    <label>  
      <input type='radio' name='rblist1' value='1' class="transformScale2">
      <span>This is the label</span>    
  </label>
  </div>
  <div class="inputRadioContainer">
    <label>  
      <input type='radio' name='rblist1' value='2' class="transformScale2">
      <span>This is the label</span>
  </label>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <input type="button" onClick="changeText()" value="Click me"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! adding top:16vh and position:absolute squashes the radio buttons.How can i get around it?